# Django build in error runtime translation

Tags: django, python-3.x, runtime-error, translation, built-in

I want to translate Django buildin errors in different languages on runtime. Is it possible to translate django error for requested user according to his region.

Answer (score 1):

Custom django run time language change
setup
Create a directory name as locale

And add this to django settings.py
    LOCALE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),]

Also add this in middleware in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [ 
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # here
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

If you want ot restrict languages you can add this in settings.py

```
LANGUAGES = [ ('en', 'English'), ('fi', 'Finnish'), ]
```

Now in terminal run this

```
django-admin makemessages -l fi
```

This command will create fi directory in locale dir
In this dir there is a .po file.
Open it and add

```
msgid "your text here"
msgstr "your translation here"
```

And run this in terminal

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

Add ‘ln’  parameter in request header for which language you want to change like ‘en’, ‘tr’, ‘fi’

For session base user run add this in init method

```
from django.utils import translation
def lang(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ln = request.META.get('HTTP_LN')
    user_language = ln
    request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
    translation.activate(user_language)
```

And user will see translated data
    Note: you can only translate that string which you have added in your PO file.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Django has a built-in module for internationalization check it out here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code